# Elasticsearch like or wildcard query against numeric fields

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

The problem is, **if the long field has value 120450, 120445, 120656.** Please find the query below.

{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"nested":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"querystring":{**"query":"120"**,"fields":["alist.articleId"]}}]}},"path":"alist"}}}_

**The response should return all the three documents which has partial match for 120.** Is it possible to achieve this in long or a numeric field ?

Comment: @val can you provide your suggestion on the above ?

Answer (score 0):

For partial matching on numerics, you can store them as `string` values.

Now, you can use either of the following

- use [edgeNGram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)
- use [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html), your field needs to be marked `not_analyzed` in this case

Comment: To achieve this we need to store the values as string. It is not possible to use numeric fields correct ?